# Span inside div does not wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is a block and have background correctly, inside this div there is a span however the span won't wrap the text inside it but instead pass over the div block.

```
<div id='code'><span class='kw'>string</span>&nbsp;str&nbsp;=&nbsp;<span class='str'>"SetResult(&#39;LINK1,LINK2&#39;,&nbsp;TagMatch(Return(TagMatch(Download(&#39;http://www.google.com\&#39;),&nbsp;&#39;&amp;lt;a&#39;,&nbsp;&#39;&#39;),&nbsp;&#39;5,6&#39;),&nbsp;&#39;onclick=gbar.logger.il(1,{t:5}); class="</span>gbzt<span class='str'>"&nbsp;id=gb_5&nbsp;href=\"&#39;,&nbsp;&#39;\"&#39;));Download(GetResult(&#39;LINK1&#39;))"</span>;<br/><span class='Var'>Scrapper</span>&nbsp;scr&nbsp;=&nbsp;<span class='kw'>new</span>&nbsp;<span class='Var'>Scrapper</span>();<br/><span class='kw'>string</span>[]&nbsp;results&nbsp;=&nbsp;scr.Multiple(str);</div>
```

You can view the problem page at here http://innosia.com/Home/Article/WEBSCRAPER
Anyone can please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `word-wrap:break-word;` in CSS but if you don't like it, use `#code{overflow:auto;}`.

On you page you have multiple IDs `code` which is not good. Try to use unique IDs.

Comment: I had to use both this answer and the one by @bangde to work. For reference, I had to set the `word-wrap` and `white-space: normal;` for it to work.

Answer (score 17):

set white-space property to normal.

```
white-space:normal;
```

Comment: In my case I used like this <span style="white-space:normal">Hello</span> and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Add the style `word-wrap:break-word` to your `span`. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This can probably be achieved with the `white-space` and `overflow` CSS properties