# Why do I get an overflow from <span>s inside a <div>?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

My HTML is really simple, but for some reason, I am getting a strange overflow. I can't seem to understand where it is coming from and how to get rid of it.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="labels">
    <span ng-repeat="label in labels">{{label}}</span>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```css
.labels {
    width: 300px;
    background: #AAFFEE;
}
```

The angular code I have is quite long (a long list of labels) but here is the gist of it:

```
angular.module('guy',[]).controller('Guy', function($scope) {
    $scope.labels = [
        'adding and subtracting',
        'audio',
        …
    ];
```

[Here is a full Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/F8Yh7je74CIA5ERWy8Su?p=preview)

Why do the `<span>` elements not wrap inside the `<div>`, but instead overflow?

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: I think that if I add a link to plunkr, it is just the same if not better.

Comment: No, it’s not better. Code that you post here will be available together with your question for people reading that question later on (and therefor they might be able to benefit from it as well, even after years), whereas code on any external site might be long gone by then.

Comment: for all close voters, I have clarified the question. please reconsider.

Comment: CBroe - well phrased.

Comment: why am I getting such a bad reaction to this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Span inside div does not wrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045990/span-inside-div-does-not-wrap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no space between your words (which is why you had to add `padding-right`), so they’re all treated as one word. This is a side-effect of Angular removing spaces<sup><sub>, which itself is a side-effect of Angular just not being very good</sub></sup>.

Put a space in.

```
<div class="labels">
  <span ng-repeat="label in labels">{{label}} </span>
</div>
```

[Voilà](http://plnkr.co/edit/gDJLUxf8EzZTVllBKebd?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and serious response. I was a bit shocked from the bad responses I got for this question. Can you please elaborate why `angular just not being very good`?

Comment: @MicahDelaneBolen: Screen readers screen readers screen readers semantics search engines

Comment: @guymograbi: Ah, ignore me :) I’m a bit against client-side templating dealies (mostly for accessibility reasons), but it’s not that serious.

Comment: @minitech: I'm uploading a screen reader test of my plunker now.

Comment: Thanks minitech. I can't thank you enough. And thanks for editing the question. I'd be lost without you.